# Lubuntu lxsession not working under VNC

Tags: lubuntu, vnc

Up until a day or two ago I had a standard Lubuntu 16.04 desktop running under TigerVNC 1.7.0. Now the desktop background is just grey instead of the Lubuntu wallpaper and right clicking it displays a menu that I don't recognise instead of the Lubuntu one, but I guess it's the openbox one. Also pcmanfm will not start. I haven't manually changed anything so I assume this is the result of a recent update.

My .vnc/startup is:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

# poll for mail every 2 minutes
fetchmail -d 120 &

#disable screensaver
xset s off

exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session lxsession -e LXDE -s Lubuntu
```

How do I go about diagnosing the problem and restoring the default Lubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was caused by running a second instance of my desktop from the console while one was already running from vncserver. It went away after a reboot and logging in from the console without vncserver running, then logging out from the console and restarting vncserver. Although I can't be sure as I wasn't really paying attention when it starting working properly again.